# Check if a string startWith a list item value

Tags: c#, string, list

I need some help with my C# code.

I have a list that contains only 2 chars strings.

`prefixes.AddRange(new string[] { "oO", "c0", "c1" });` // and many others

I want to check if a value entered by a user begin by of these item (the value is entered through a textbox) ?

For exemple, the result I want is to verify if my user enter "123456789" (that not begin by an item of my list), then add for example "000" automatically before : "000123456789".

I guess i can achieve this by LinQ, but I wondering how to do this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So if I understand you correct, you want to add "000" if it *not* begins with 2 chars from the list?

Comment: `bool result = prefixes.Any(prefix => userInput.StartsWith(prefix));`

Comment: `prefixes.Contains(userInput.Substring(0,2))` ?

Comment: @vasily.sib: `userInput.Substring(0,2)` will *throw exception* on short `userInput` (e.g. `userInput = "*"`)

Comment: @DmitryBychenko sure, and `prefixes.Any(prefix => userInput.StartsWith(prefix))` will _throw exception_ if `prefix` is `null` (e.g. `prefixes.Add(null)`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each prefix you need to check if usersText starts with it. Below code will check it and add "000" to your usersText.

```
if(!prefixes.Any(p => usersText.StartsWith(p))
{
    usersText = "000" + usersText;
}
```

Comment: It works but if usersText begins by a string contained in my list, it adds "000" also. Is there any way to avoid this ?

Comment: I'm confused, so it works or not? The only possibility for it not to work is probably character casing. Can you show an example where this solution doesn't work?

Comment: Oh you're right... but I convert my strings in my list toUpper before working with it... I had to convert user entry toUpper too to make this to work. My issue is now solved. Thank's :)

Answer (score 1):

What @piotr said, but i'd probably wrap in in a method to hide the ugly bits away.
Assuming prefixes are global, you can do:

```
public string GetPrefix(string s) {
      return prefixes.Any(p => s.StartsWith(p))
           ? "" : "000"
}
```

and then use it.
Or even as en extension method on string if you'd like ...

```
public static string GetPrefixForString(this string[] prefixes, string s) {
      return prefixes.Any(p => s.StartsWith(p))
           ? "" : "000"
}

// Usage: 
var foo = prefixes.GetPrefixForString(bar);
```